# Open file with blank spaces in filename matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I open file like this:

```
fid = fopen('2016 05 23_filename.dat','rt');
```

i.e the filename contains spaces.

The global point is open all files in current folder, and write them to data.

Comment: uh, whats the issue here?

Comment: Exactly as you've written it?

Comment: You open up the file using the code seen in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627879/open-file-with-blank-spaces-in-filename-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue in how you have this written. The only reason you may be having issues is if you typed the filename in incorrectly. You can check this by scripting it to open all files in your folder:

```
files = dir('*.dat');
for k = 1:numel(files)
    fid = fopen(files(k).name, 'rt');

    %// Do stuff
    fclose(fid);
end
```